# Android - Circular array

Tags: android, arrays

I have a array of jokes
String jokes[]={"x","y","z","j"};
i am using two methods next and previous to go front and back.

```
public void nextJoke(View view) {
        if (jokeNumber < jokes.length - 1) {
            jokeNumber++;
            tv1.setText(jokes[jokeNumber]);

  }
    }

    public void prevJoke(View view) {
        if (jokeNumber > 0) {
            jokeNumber--;
            tv1.setText(jokes[jokeNumber]);

        }
```

I want to give this list a endless scroll functionality . 
That means if the user next or previous - and list reaches the last three elements , it should again start from first element.

How can i achieve this functionality .
This is more of a programming question .
Any Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is this some kind of joke?

Answer (score 4):

Using the remainder operator, you'll get the required behavior.

Replace:

```
jokeNumber++;
```

with:

```
jokeNumber = ++jokeNumber % jokes.length;
```

and do the same for `jokeNumber--;`

Answer (score 0):

On next:

```
next(){
 jokeNumber++;
 if(jokeNumber>=jokes.length) { jokeNumber =0;}
}
```

on previous:

```
previous(){
 jokeNumber--;
 if(jokeNumber<=0) { jokeNumber =jokes.length;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void nextJoke(View view) {
    if (jokeNumber < jokes.length ) {
        jokeNumber = ++jokeNumber % jokes.length;
        tv1.setText(jokes[jokeNumber]); } }

public void prevJoke(View view) {
    if (jokeNumber > 0) {
        jokeNumber = --jokeNumber % jokes.length;
        tv1.setText(jokes[jokeNumber]);

    }
```